# HTML5 History API - Persisting page state after leaving page

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I'm working with the HTML5 History API and ajax to load partial page content whenever possible. I have most of this working correctly, however, there are some instances where a full page reload is required and this is where things seem to break.

I'm adding to the history using `pushState`:

`history.pushState({ data: response }, '', href);`

I've got an event listener on the `popstate` event that displays the correct content when navigating back:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e)
{
    if (e.state) {
        $('#content').html(e.state.data);
    }
});`
```

Everything works fine until I navigate to a URL that requires a full page reload (not loaded via ajax) and then use the browsers back button. The entire page is then replaced only with the previous ajax response.

Is there something I can do to render the page correctly in an instance like this? I realise I could return the entire html page on every ajax request but this seems wasteful when the majority of content won't be changing.

Comment: Take a look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003911/how-to-restore-page-on-back-history/28004222#28004222

Comment: I've been able to resolve my issue with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241263/html5-history-api-back-button-with-partial-page-loads